# launch.h deprecated methods

Tags: cocoa, launch

I wrote an Helper Tool for an application based on http://dl.dropbox.com/u/463624/Elevator.zip, but setting the deployment target to 10.10 now I can see deprecation in lauch.h, this is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <launch.h>
#import <syslog.h>
#import "HelperTool.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "MyHelper launched (uid: %d, euid: %d, pid: %d)", getuid(), geteuid(), getpid());

        launch_data_t req = launch_data_new_string(LAUNCH_KEY_CHECKIN);
        launch_data_t resp = launch_msg(req);
        launch_data_t machData = launch_data_dict_lookup(resp, LAUNCH_JOBKEY_MACHSERVICES);
        launch_data_t machPortData = launch_data_dict_lookup(machData, "com.me.MyHelper.mach");

        mach_port_t mp = launch_data_get_machport(machPortData);
        launch_data_free(req);
        launch_data_free(resp);

        NSMachPort *rp = [[NSMachPort alloc] initWithMachPort:mp];
        NSConnection *c = [NSConnection connectionWithReceivePort:rp sendPort:nil];

        //.....

    }
    return 0;
}
```

looking here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10SeedDiff/headers/System.html no big changes, but how to solve?

Comment: all inside launch.h appear to be deprecated..

Comment: Try this: http://atnan.com/blog/2012/02/29/modern-privileged-helper-tools-using-smjobbless-plus-xpc/